# Can Windows domain administrator selectively allow some setup files to be installed (updated) by the users without elevated rights (mass deployment)?

Tags: permissions, domain, installation, automated-install, setuptools

I am producing installation files for my program with InnoSetup - result is an exe installation file that contains the software exe and some additional files. Usually the administartor rights are required to install or update the program using such installation files. My question is - can system administrator of the Windows domain can somehow mark the fresh installation exe file that everyon in the domain can install it wihout elevated rights or that elevated rights are granted for one time for installation/updating from such programs.

I have heard, that *.msi setup files can be run remotely inside the domain upon request of administrator. Maybe such mechanisms exist for other kind of setup files as well?

Here is description https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html of installations as Group Policy Options. So, the question is - should I create installation in *.msi format for such mass deployment be possible, or any instllation format will suffice?

Answer (score 1):

> ... can system administrator ... mark the fresh installation exe file that everyone in the domain can install it wihout elevated rights or that elevated rights are granted for one time for installation/updating from such programs.

Short answer - No.

If the User wants/needs to install software, then they *must* have to have the permissions to do so.  There is no way around this and it's a Good Thing.

However, there are many frameworks and utilities that can take this job *away* from Users, installing the software *on their behalf*.  [It's a bit of a sledgehammer, but] "Configuration Manager", part of Microsoft's Service Manager suite, is one such utility.